# 404 Not found when installing packages

Tags: 16.04, apt

I have a script that has been working well until now and suddenly I get the following message:

```
Get:81 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 python-software-properties all 0.96.20.7 [20.7 kB]
Get:82 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 python3-pycurl amd64 7.43.0-1ubuntu1 [42.3 kB]
Get:83 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 python3-software-properties all 0.96.20.7 [20.3 kB]
Get:84 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 software-properties-common all 0.96.20.7 [9452 B]
Get:85 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 xz-utils amd64 5.1.1alpha+20120614-2ubuntu2 [78.8 kB]
Err:86 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 unattended-upgrades all 0.90ubuntu0.7
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Fetched 23.7 MB in 1s (14.8 MB/s)
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5-minimal_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/libpython3.5-stdlib_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python3.5/python3.5_3.5.2-2ubuntu0~16.04.2_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.32-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.90ubuntu0.7_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

It seems that when running:

```
apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
```

Some server is down. How can I avoid having this dependency?
This is part of a continuous integration server and I would like to avoid these problems in the future.

NOTE: I ran `sudo apt update` before.. This is in fact, part of a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install software-properties-common python-software-properties
RUN apt-get -y install ca-certificates curl
RUN apt-get -y install build-essential git sudo
```

building the container fails in the second line.

Comment: Did you run `sudo apt update` before?

Comment: Unfortunately yes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [docker best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/), I should put the update and install in the same RUN line. This way the cache will be updated properly.

After these changes, things are working.

Comment: `apt-get update` one one line followed by `apt-get install X` on the next line is completely equivalent to a single line of `apt-get update && sudo apt-get install X`. If the problem apparently went away after this change, the problem was actually an intermittently out-of-sync package repository. Those are bound to happen occasionally with the way package repositories are currently managed.

Comment: it is a tiny bit different because Docker is caching per line. So some lines might not get executed again.

Comment: I believe @JuanLeni is correct. They are not equivalent, and the `apt-get update` might get an undesirable cache.

Comment: Thanks, after almost an hour browsing and wondering how this stopped working with no changes your solution was the only one that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running into this issue while using Docker, you may need to run the docker build command with the `--no-cache` option to get it to start again from the beginning.

Comment: Worked for me. Apparently once an intermediate docker image gets "stuck" on a certain bad mirror it stays there. I suspect one could also delete all the intermediate docker images before rebuilding, instead of using `--no-cache`.

Answer (score 1):

The files have been removed from the server for some reason.

Open up a new browser window and copy/paste the following in the URL address bar and hit Enter and see for yourself:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.90ubuntu0.7_all.deb

http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.32-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

You can also try:

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/u/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades_0.90ubuntu0.7_all.deb

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libidn/libidn11_1.32-3ubuntu1.1_amd64.deb
```

and you will get the same error.

Can you please post the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

```
cat /etc/apt/sources.list
```

You just need to edit the URLs in the file to redirect APT to different servers and run `sudo apt update` and try again.

Look what happens when I visit one of the URLs from my end:

[image]

This is why it fails. You need to change the server reference.

Comment: Thanks. I am using the official ubuntu image for docker. Redirecting to other servers would be too error prone.. more like manual patching. I think the reason was because that line was not following docker best practices and the update line was cached.

Comment: Yes, it was clear to me that the files were not there. Servers can be updated frequently and that is fine.